# Async pass multiple parameters into ReportProgress method

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

How can I pass multiple parameters into the `ReportProgress` method?
I was following this guide: [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/) to create a progressbar. My code looks like this.

`MainWindow.xaml`

```
public User User { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.User = new User();
    this.DataContext = User;
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<int>(ReportProgress); //here is the error
    await this.User.ReadUsers(progressIndicator, this.User)
}

void ReportProgress(int value, User pUser)
{
    this.User.Val = value;
}
```

`User.xaml`

```
public async Task<bool> ReadUsers(IProgress<int> pProgress, User pUser)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        pProgress.Report(i, pUser);
    }

    return true;
}
```

As you may see, I was trying to add simply a new parameter (`User pUser`) to the `ReportProgress` method. Now I get an error inside the `Button_Click` method (line is marked).

> Argument 1: cannot convert from method group into System.Action
>
> best overloaded method match for 'System.Progress.Progress(System.Action)'-method has some invalid arguments
>
> no overload for `Report-Method` takes 2 arguments

I was trying it like this, because in my real application I will have an `ObersableCollection<User>`. Is there maybe a better way I should go?

Comment: Progress alreay allows you to report multiple values. Just use a class with the fields you need instead of an `int`, or even a `Tuple<int,string>`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it works. Thanks alot!

Comment: why are you using `Progress` instead of subscribing to the `ObservableCollection`? Your code isn't reporting progress, it updates another DTO in response to changes to a collection. If you care about binding for example, WPF *does* update itself to changes to a collection

Comment: Yes, I am using binding. Can you give me a little example with using the `ObservableCollection`? (I - think - I know how to use it generally, but I don't know how to use it in this case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass a second parameter manually, because 'Progress' constructor takes only actions with one argument. Try this:

```
new Progress<int>(i => ReportProgress(i, this.User));
```

And remove second argument from 'pProgress.Report' method:

```
pProgress.Report(i);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer creating a message and pass multiple values to Report Progress

```
public class RMssg
{
    public int ProgressIndicator { get; set; }
    public User userInstance { get; set; }
}

private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var progressIndicator = new Progress<RMssg>(r => ReportProgress(r));
    await this.User.ReadUsers(progressIndicator, this.User);
}

void ReportProgress(RMssg rMssg)
{
    this.User.Val = rMssg.ProgressIndicator;
    var user = rMssg.userInstance;
}



public async Task<bool> ReadUsers(IProgress<RMssg> pProgress, User pUser)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(500);
        var rMssg = new RMssg() { ProgressIndicator = i, userInstance = pUser };
        pProgress.Report(rMssg);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Note that the OP isn't using `Progress` to report progress but to update another DTO. The `userInstance` value isn't used.

Comment: this worked great for me - thanks for posting this!